# Implementing asynchronous scoping in PCL and Windows Phone applications

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-phone

For some weird reason, both the [System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AsyncLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes are only available using the full CLR. This makes it really hard to do asynchronous scoping while working with Portable Class Libraries or Windows Phone applications, especially since Windows Phone APIs are becoming async-only; so we don't really have an option in not using async/await.

What this practically means is that in WPF or WinForms, we can write methods like this:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("x", new object());
    await Something();
    var context = CallContext.LogicalGetData("x");
}
```

In WPF and WinForms, the framework ensures that each click to the same button get their own context and with that can run in isolation. It's hard to achieve the same using `ThreadLocal<T>` and `[ThreadStatic]` since every click will get executed on the UI thread.

**My question is, how would we solve this problem in Windows Phone, Store and other application types that don't support `CallContext` and `AsyncLocal<T>`?**

*Some background information:*

Very often we want (business) logic to run in some sort of context. This context can contain information that the business logic can use throughout the operation. In a server environment this is really easy to imagine, because you need to run requests in a database transaction, need to access the current user, tenant id, etc. But even in a client application, operations might need to access contextual information such as a correlation id for the current running operation or context for logging. During such operation (like an click event) we might need to resolve additional services (from our [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)). For the operation to work successfully, we might need to reuse the same component throughout the entire client operation and that means that our Composition Root needs to be aware of the context it is running.

Although all this information can be passed on through the entire system using method calls of the services' public API, this would not only force us to pollute the API of the services in our application with implementation details, it would lead to severe maintenance issues, because we would have to pass through all this information throughout the system, and a simple internal change to one of our components would propagate up the call stack through all the methods calls. And when it comes to our Composition Root, we definitely don't want to pass though some cache/scope object of our DI library through the application, because that would tightly couple our business logic to an external library. Obviously, neither do we want to pass on some sort of [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

So implementing scoping using something like `CallContext` or `AsyncLocal<T>` is very important in client applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy solution for this today, sorry. When Windows Phone (eventually) becomes "Windows 10 on a phone" (i.e., with `AsyncLocal<T>`), then this will be possible. But for now...

The easiest way to do this is to pass the context, either explicitly (as a parameter) or implicitly (as a member variable on `this`).

It may also be possible to achieve a limited version of this with custom awaiters. But in addition to being horribly complex, that solution would require you to modify every `await` in your entire app (or use a post-compilation IL rewriting to achieve the same effect).

Comment: Crap. Not the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: @Steven: Sorry! As a consolation prize, you are welcome to believe that implicit contexts are not a great design. They're good for logging context (grouping multiple log messages into a single logical "activity"), and that's about it. Invisible contexts are a poor mechanism for true business data/logic - they make the system difficult to test and maintain. I write tons of async code and (except for "activity" correlation), I only use implicit contexts to create causality stacks when debugging, never in production and certainly never carrying business-layer information.

Comment: I agree it's bad for business logic, but transparent contexts (like the `TransactionScope`) are great for infrastructural concerns and they actually make the life of developers much easier. [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) (a DI lib) has based its design of scoped lifestyles around this concept and this makes the developer's life much easier, because it allows their business logic to be completely oblivious of the scope it is running in. Passing through the DI container's scope throughout the system leads to strong coupling on the DI container, which is bad practice.